# programmatically create one bean block to the default theme

Tags: theming, database, blocks

I am trying to programmatically create beans in a custom module using entity_metadata_wrapper. This is creating a bean for each installed theme. (In Drupal 7)

**Is there a way I can create only one instance of the bean block?**

for example in my database it creates a bean block for

- my subtheme
- omega
- seven

I would like to only create one block/bean for my subtheme. I am then using mymodule_beans_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {} to then change region location and other block parameters.

```
function bean_ctas_enable(){
    foreach(bean_ctas_info() as $bean_content){
        $bean_ids = array();
        $bean = bean_create(array('type' => 'block_cta'));
        $bean_wrap = entity_metadata_wrapper('bean', $bean);
        $bean_wrap->label->set($bean_content['label']);
        $bean_wrap->title->set($bean_content['title']);
        $bean_wrap->field_text->set(array(
            'value' => ($bean_content['field_text']),
            'format' => ('full_html'),
            ));
        $bean_wrap->field_link->set(array(
            'url' => ($bean_content['link_url']),
            'title' => 'Read More',
        ));
        $bean_wrap->save();
        $bean_ids[] = $bean_wrap->bid->value();
        //set variable to store bean ids
        variable_set('bean_ctas_bean_ids', $bean_ids);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `hook_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks)` to alter the blocks in my custom modules .module file

inside of my  hook_block_info_alter i wrote an if statment

```
if($blocks['bean'][$key]['theme'] == variable_get('theme_default', '0')){}
```

to make sure I was only altering regions only for my default theme